# Jumpy video in scenes with movement

Tags: ffmpeg

i am trying to recode a video from 4096 to 3840 which i did succesfully with this line:

ffmpeg -i C:\Alien.mkv -vf scale=3840:2160 -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -acodec copy D:\Alien1.mkv -hide_banner

But the result video seems jumpy, like there is a pause between frames and it happens only when the scene has movement. The input and output framerate is the same (23976). Dont know what to do.

Comment: Is it jumpy in all scenes with motion?

Comment: yes, only when there is movement involved

Comment: when people stay put making conversation is fine, but as soon as they start moving it goes jumpy

Comment: Make sure that you use recent ffmpeg, and not some other older or fork version.